# Gestion de Inventario en C++

Tags: c++, date

El programa es un control de inventario que captura información de productos, como cantidad, precios mayoreo y menudeo, fecha.

Cuando el usuario escoge la opción de **Comprar**, el programa pide la información del producto nuevo a ingresar, al llegar al apartado de `Fecha`, lo salta, **no me deja ingresar la fecha**.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void addRecord(fstream &);
void viewRecord(fstream &);
void changeRecord(fstream &);
int menu();

const int DESC_SIZE = 21;
const int DATE_SIZE = 11;

struct inventoryData
{
    char desc[DESC_SIZE]; //Hasta  20 chars
    int quantity; //Cantidad del Producto
    double wholesale; //Costo Mayoreo
    double retail; //Costo Menudeo
    char date[DATE_SIZE]; //Fecha xx/xx/xxxx
};
int main()
{
    fstream dataFile("inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (dataFile.fail())
    {
        // El archivo no existe se tiene que crear.
        dataFile.open("inventory.dat", ios::out);
        dataFile.close();
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        int selection = menu();
        if (selection == 4)
        break;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                viewRecord(dataFile);
                break;
            case 2:
                addRecord(dataFile);
                break;
            case 3:
                changeRecord(dataFile);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalido - Favor de usar 1 a 4" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void addRecord(fstream &notused)
{
    fstream file("inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    inventoryData item;

    cout << "Porfavor Ingrese la siguiente informacion del producto" << endl;
    cout << "Descripcion: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(item.desc, DESC_SIZE);

    cout << "Cantidad: ";
    cin >> item.quantity;

    cout << "Precio Mayoreo: ";
    cin >> item.wholesale;

    cout << "Precio Menudeo: ";
    cin >> item.retail;

    cout << "Fecha (Favor de usar MES/DIA/ANO formato: ";
    cin.getline(item.desc, DATE_SIZE);

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&item), sizeof(item));

    return;
}
void viewRecord(fstream &notused)
{
    fstream dataFile("inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    inventoryData item;
    while (dataFile)
    {
        dataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item));
        // Display the record.
        cout << "Descripcion: " << item.desc << endl;
        cout << "Cantidad: " << item.quantity << endl;
        cout << "Precio Mayoreo: " << item.wholesale << endl;
        cout << "Precio Menudeo: " << item.retail << endl;
        cout << "Fecha: " << item.date << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void changeRecord(fstream &file)
{
    fstream dataFile("inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    inventoryData item;
    int recordNumber;

    cout << "Porfavor escoge el numero de record para modificarlo" << endl;
    cin >> recordNumber;
    dataFile.seekg(recordNumber * sizeof(item), ios::beg);
    dataFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&item), sizeof(item));
    cout << "Descripcion: " << item.desc << endl;
    cout << "Cantidad: " << item.quantity << endl;
    cout << "Precio Mayoreo: " << item.wholesale << endl;
    cout << "Precio Menudeo: " << item.retail << endl;
    cout << "Fecha: " << item.date << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Agregar datos nuevos.
    cout << "Ingresa Nuevos Datos:\n";
    cout << "Descripcion: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(item.desc, DESC_SIZE);
    cout << "Cantidad: ";
    cin >> item.quantity;
    cout << "Precio Mayoreo: ";
    cin >> item.wholesale;
    cout << "Precio Menudeo: ";
    cin >> item.retail;
    cout << "Fecha (Porfavor ingresa fecha MES/DIA/ANO formato: ";
    cin >> item.date;

    // Regresa al principio
    dataFile.seekp(recordNumber * sizeof(item), ios::beg);
    // Escribir record nuevo encima de uno existente
    dataFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&item), sizeof(item));
}
int menu()
{
    int menuSelection = 0;//initialize

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "----------Inventario----------" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Ver Inventario" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Comprar" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Vender" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Terminar Programa" << endl;

    //*** flush cin, es un inside loop, creo que aqui esta causando problemas\
    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);
    cin >> menuSelection;

    return menuSelection;
}
```

Comment: Hola Guille, tu pregunta es muy amplia. Este sitio funciona mejor si expones una sola pregunta en cada publicación. Puedes hacer todas las preguntas que necesites, solo debes explicar de forma clara cual es el error específico que tienes. Y no olvides incluir en cada pregunta un __[mcve]__.

Comment: A los últimos que votan para cerrar... ¿de verdad os habéis leído la pregunta? pone bien claro que lo que sucede es que no consigue leer la fecha...

Comment: En el código dice: _"flush cin, es un inside loop, creo que aqui esta causando problemas"_  Estoy de acuerdo con @eferion

Comment: En especial mi queja va hacia los dos últimos votantes, los votos anteriores fueron previos a la edición de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> item.retail;
cin.getline(item.desc, DATE_SIZE);
```

Las llamadas a `cin`, por defecto, no eliminan el salto de línea final. Es al volver a llamar a `cin` cuando se detecta y se descarta dicho salto de línea. El problema es que tras esa llamada realizas otra a `getline`. Esta función lee hasta que se encuentra un salto de línea.

¿resultado final? La fecha está en blanco.

La solución es simple, descarta el último carácter de cin (o vaciarlo directamente):

```
cin >> item.retail;
cin.ignore(); //descartar 1 carácter
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()); // vaciar buffer
cin.getline(item.desc, DATE_SIZE);
```

Dicho esto, `fflush` solo es seguro usarlo en buffers de salida. **nunca** de entrada. Para vaciar el buffer de entrada tienes que usar `ignore`.